# Как сделать справочный инфоблоки?

Tags: битрикс

Задача: Добавить элемент в инфоблок.

Структура: Есть 4 инфоблок. Инфоблок1(динамичный), Инфоблок2(у него 3 элемент), Инфоблок3(у него 3 элемент), Инфоблок4(динамичный).

Цель: При добавлении элемент в инфоблок(моем случае Инфоблок4) Инфоблок1, Инфоблок2, Инфоблок3 должен быть как выпадающий, я выбираю только 1 элемент(название) каждое из них. Потом отправлять у них id. Эти все надо делать через битрикс администратор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мое мнение(вопрос):
1. Можно так сделать, если да тогда как можно сделать?
2.Или есть другой вариант?

Спасибо всем!

Comment: Пожалуйста яснее и грамотнее сформулируйте ваш вопрос. Правильно ли я понимаю, что для инфоблока №4 должно поле в которое вы должны внести элементы из 3 других инфоблоков?

Comment: Nikolaj Sarry, да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В административной панели перейдите в "Контент"-"Инфоблоки"-"Типы инфоблоков" выберите нужный тип инфоблока и инфоблок в вашем случае "Инфоблок 4". Перейдите на вкладку "Свойства". Создайте свойство или свойства с типом "Привязка к элементу" или "Привязка к элементу с автозаполнением" или "Привязка к элементам в виде списка". Затем нажмите на кнопку с тремя точками в колонке "Изм." и в параметре "Информационный блок" укажите из какого инфоблока будут предлагаться элементы.